# RabbitMQ inside docker won't end gracefully and cannot reconnect

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, amqp, docker-compose, docker-container

I am trying to do RPC with RabbitMQ inside 2 docker containers. I have set them up as follows:

```
chindow:
 image: bablot/chindow
 ports:
   - "9999:9999"
 links:
   - rabbitmq:amq

rabbitmq:
 image: rabbitmq:3
 ports:
   - "15672:15672"
```

Everything works as expected initially, but then, when I shut down the system with `ctrl+c` it results in the following error:

`babelotserver_rabbitmq_1 exited with code 143`

and then when I proceed to reboot the system:

```
chindow_1  | { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.3:5672]
             code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
             errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
             syscall: 'connect',
             address: '172.17.0.3',
             port: 5672 }
```

EDIT:

When I `docker stop` rabbitmq I get `code 143`
When I `docker stop` node.js I get `code 0`

Why are these 2 different? Is this meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using [docker-compose format Version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2).

It will create a bridge network: see "[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)"

That will allow your containers to stop and re-start while still being able to see/contact each other.

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app.
>   Each container for a service joins the default network and is both *reachable* by other containers on that network, and *discoverable* by them at a hostname identical to the container name.